# Paypal error We’re sorry Things don’t appear to be working at the moment

Tags: php, html, paypal

We’re sorry Things don’t appear to be working at the moment. This error comes each time while transacting through paypal.

Here is the url for live testing http://shreyasoft.in/paypal/ but not working from sandbox

Here is my paypal form

```
paypal_form.php
```

here is the code for sandbox account

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank">
   <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
   <input type="hidden" name="business" value="sethiharshit92-facilitator@gmail.com">
   <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Widget">
   <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10.00"> 
   <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value='http://localhost/paypal/paypal_cancel.php'>
    <input type='hidden' name='return' value='http://localhost/paypal/paypal_success.php'>
   <input type="submit" value="Old PayPal checkout">
</form>
```

here is the error
[image: paypal]

Comment: I haven't used the PayPal API before, but my guess would be that the error appears because you're using localhost URLs rather than a proper domain.

Comment: Its nothing problem with url I have changed with the server proper domain also but giving the same error

Answer (score 2):

Paypal needs to be able to contact yourwebhost directly to validate the authentication.

it works like this:

1. you send request to paypal
2. paypal sends request to your site with key
3. your site needs to respond with proper answer
4. paypal continues transaction.

step 2 is failing at this point because paypal cannot contact your localhost.

Either use a webserver with a domain name/public ip, or set up your internet router to route traffic to port 80 to your development pc and use your public ip in communication with paypal

Comment: At the server also the same thing happens, paypal sends request to your site with key, can you please ellaborate how can I check the step 2? Is there is the problem with the sandbox

Comment: https://www.evoluted.net/thinktank/web-development/paypal-php-integration check out step 4.

Comment: At server !! Return to test facilitator's Test Store !!! At this time, we are unable to process your request. Please return to test facilitator's Test Store and try another option.

Comment: Again the same thing happens @Tschallacka the link you provided, the code is being copied with the changes on the server and the same error occured  https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYiBW.png

Comment: I am working on paypal sandbox payment and it was working fine but since an hour it stopped working and giving the error page given in the question.